# Prove that for all sets $A,B,C$, $A − (B \cup C) = (A − B) − C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that for all sets $A,B,C$,

$A − (B \cup C) = (A − B) − C$.

Comment: What is the difficulty? Both sides represent the set of elements that are in $A$, but not in $B$ or $C$.

Comment: Done, now what?

Answer (score 2):

$(A-B)-C=(A\cap B^c)\cap C^c=A\cap (B^c\cap C^c ) = A\cap (B\cup C)^c=A-(B\cup C) $

Comment: You can use `\cap` to represent $\cap$

Comment: @choco_addicted thanks for helping ☺

Comment: One may add an intermediate step between the second and third steps: use associativity of $\cap$ first, then the interplay between $\cap, \cup$ and the complement operation.

Comment: @bartgol sure i edited .☺

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are two sets in the universe, then $X-Y$ can be rewritten as $X \cap Y'$, where $Y'$ denotes the complement of $Y$ in the universe.

The left hand side is $A-(B \cup C) = A \cap (B \cup C)' = A \cap (B' \cap C')$, where the last equality is by DeMorgan. The right hand side is $(A-B)-C = (A-B) \cap C' = (A \cap B') \cap C'$.  Since $\cap$ is associative, the two sides are equal.